# Symfony route with several optional params

Tags: php, symfony, routes, optional-parameters

first of all thanks for reading. I got a problem with Symfony routes. I got a single route that receives several parameters:

```
my_route:
    path:     /route/{page}/{paramA}/{paramB}/{paramC}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:MyController:index, page: null, paramA: null, paramB: null, paramC: null }
```

The problem is with "paramA". Its a text to filter results, and it could  be unset, but "paramB" and "paramC" could be.

So I need that route to handle for example:

```
/route/1/paramB/paramC
```

and receive in controller:

```
paramA = null, paramB="paramB", paramC="paramC"
```

Right now when I handle:

```
/route/1/paramB/paramC
```

I get this in the controller:

```
paramA="paramB", paramB="paramC", paramC=null
```

Any help would be welcome. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know how you envisage that working. You might know when you write the URL which parameter is supposed to be which, but how can the Symfony Controller receiving the request know? You will have to choose a different default value, and fill the URL accordingly.

Comment: I know wich parameter is wich when I write the url. The problem is that when it's text and it's empty it's no written, for example:

The user types for filtering:

    /route/1/textToFind/paramB/paramC

Theres no problem, and I know that "textToFind" is paramA. But if he/she filters just by paramB and paramC so the route is:

    /route/paramB/paramC

The value of paramB is stored in paramA. That's what I try to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional parameters like these for filtering, sorting and pagination should be passed as query params, route params should only point to desired resource.

So:

`/article?page=0&limit=10`

not:

`/article/0/10`

Or:

`/user?active=1`

not:

`/user/1`

And so on.

If you have a complex example, share it with us.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to do it on Symfony2. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Could you share an example controller?
If you extend Controller class, you can access query params with: ````$this->request->query->get(KEY)````

Comment: Do you need the whole controller? Or just a few lines. It's a big one, thats why I ask. I'll post an example when I arrive home. Thanks for everithing :)

Comment: Whole controller would be better. You can skip some valuable parts (for us) because you think they're not important. Post it on pastebin (or something similiar), maybe we can help you with refactoring to make it better overall.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. As mentioned in Symfony documentation

> You can have more than one optional placeholder,
>  but everything after
>   an optional placeholder must be optional.

You've added following to the defaults key,

```
page: null, paramA: null, paramB: null, paramC: null
```

So everything after key `page` should be there in the URL, same goes for `paramA`. So when you want to skip one value you must skip the following  values in your case.

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements

Comment: Well, in fact "paramB" and "paramC" are also optional. I need something like the usual url: /route/1?paramA=paramA&paramB=paramB&paramC=paramC

Comment: Yeah that's true, but you cannot skip that param. Check my updated answer.